# Bind location to MapView in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

Just wonder how can I bind a latitude and longitude to `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`. Feels like it doesn't expose any layout attributes for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer myself.

Just need to create static method annotated with @BindingAdapter.
Something like:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:latLong")
public static void bindLocationToMap(MapView mapView, LatLng latLong) {
   CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 10);
   mapView.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

And use attribute defined above in layout:

```
...
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:location="@{latLong} />
...
```

Comment: But is the `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView ` the right way to use the maps? I mean, every documentation tells you to use a fragment, and I'm wondering if this is a deprecated way.

Comment: Im curious about what jturolla ask too. But I understand that you can use @BindingAdapter the same way with the new way? I'm just getting started with mvvm so I'm a bit confused about who should deal with the map updates.

Comment: as far as I know it's not forbidden to use MapView itself (what MapFragment does itself) but you just need to take care of delivering lifecycle events to the MapView